# Review only a part of a merge request in Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, merge-request

In merge request page Gitlab offers a tab "Changes" that show the sum of all the differences made in all the commits.
This is useful for final review instead of checking single commits that may revert or touch same lines of code.

I wonder if it is possible to check the changes of only a part of the merge request instead of the overall sum.
My use case is the following: I reviewed a merge request and ask my colleague for some modification. He implements them and I want to check straightly *only* the last things he modified.

As "Changes" view is now it is hard to detect only the few things added in respect of all modifications. Does somebody knows if it possible and how to do it?

Comment: There is a link `Compare with previous version` on the MR page. Besides, on the diff page of a MR commit, there is a button `Show latest version`. Press it and then you can select the left version and the right version. It allows you to compare any 2 of the versions, or any version against the base. In you case, you can compare the last 2 versions.

Comment: Thanks! Why don't you answer so I can vote you up?

Answer (score 1):

When you go on the "Changes"-tab, there are two drop-down menus which usually say "Compare master and latest version" where you can choose which versions of the MR you want to compare. Furthermore, when you go to the "Overview"-Tab, you can search for the activity where your colleague implemented your changes and click on "Compare with previous version" right next to it. Lastly, you can always go on the "Commits"-tab and review each commit separately.